# shinyDND with uiOutput not working

Tags: r, jquery-ui, shiny, htmlwidgets

I am attempting to use shinyDND from the server side using uiOuput, renderUI and dragUI but the divs created are not draggable. Example:

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyDND)

  ui <- shinyUI(
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("myUI"),
      dragUI("works","works")

    )
  )

  server = shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
    output$myUI <- renderUI({
      dragUI("doesntwork","doesntwork")
    })
  })

  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The dragUI element being created within the renderUI function is visible but not draggable. The dragUI element in the ui function is fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/ayayron/shinydnd

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53283202/how-to-refer-to-reactive-element-in-ui-r-in-shiny

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug and has since been fixed

Comment: Is this a working answer to your question? I mean, I know that is not. And as such, it should not be written as an answer. It should be added to the question in an edit